# Different table in different database in Yii2 app

Tags: php, yii2

I have a yii2 app. I want to use different database for some tables.

My db2.php

```
<?php
return [
    'tablePrefix' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    'schemaCacheDuration' => 86400,
    'schemaCache' => 'cache',
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=testdb2',
    'username' => 'testdb2',
    'password' => 'testdb2pass',
];
```

web.php

```
'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
'db2' => require(__DIR__ . '/db2.php'),
```

For example my app should read and write to db.php but when there is any user related task it should read and write to db2.php

I tried creating separate file for db2 connection called db2.php and added it on web.php

Answer (score 0):

You can change the db-connection dynamicaly for the concerned models:

```
public static function getDb()
{
    // return Yii::$app->get('db');
    return (<<test == true>>) ? Yii::$app->get('db') : Yii::$app->get('db2');
}
```